# Paserver on Macos Catalina

Tags: firemonkey, macos-catalina, delphi-10.3-rio, rad-studio, paserver

I try to connect rad studio Rio with Macos Catalina using PaServer(last version) , but it not starting and show me message "**paserverManager" need to be updated**

Answer (score 0):

you need to launch it through the PAServermanager of the version 10.3.2 (the updated version)
it works fine for me.